# What happens to dependent Debian packages when you upgrade a Debian package?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, deb

Let's say I have a debian package `A-1.0.0.deb` (which contains a library), and another package `B-1.0.0.deb` (which contains a service) which depends on the `A` library.  Now let's say I want to upgrade to `A-1.0.1.deb`.

According to [this document](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-maintainerscripts.html), `dpkg` goes through a pretty involved algorithm to figure which package maintainer scripts are called for each package as part of the upgrade process.  If some of these steps fail, then `A` can be left in some sort of limbo state (for example, "Half-installed").

However, when you break `A`, then `B` is broken too since it depends on `A`.  So my question is does `dpkg` have any built-in way to deal with this situation?  Does `B`'s install status change depending on `A`'s status?  Ideally `dpkg` would have some built-in functionality to move `B` from the installed state to another state (so that the `B` service can be stopped & restarted when `A` is healthy), but I can't find anything in the `dpkg` documentation that suggests this is done.

If `dpkg` doesn't handle this situation intelligently, does `apt`?

Answer (score 6):

From what I have experienced not what i have read.

- > However, when you break A, then B is broken too since A depends on it. So my question is does dpkg have any built-in way to deal with this situation?

  Yes, it will try to reinstall or reconfigure A on next run.

  1. If it was just interrupted, it will fix that and continue working as normal.
  2. But it's a problem with control scripts, it will fail again and again and it stay in this loop. Then it's a bug and report would be filled against that package and a manual fix is required.
- > Does B's install status change depending on A's status?

  No, the status stay as Installed no change, but it does keep track of broken dependency too, at least not in the same file `/var/lib/dpkg/status`.
- > If dpkg doesn't handle this situation intelligently, does apt?

  No, APT does not interfere in this case. `apt` uses `dpkg`, dpkg is the lower level tool and it is the only tool that actually install, build, remove Debian packages.

---

Let's try it, better it is done in a virtualbox.

1. Prepare dummy packages

   ```
   ~$ sudo apt install equivs
   ~$ mkdir deleteme
   ~$ cd deleteme
   ```

   B 1.0.0 depends on A

   ```
   ~/deleteme$ equivs-control b0
   ~/deleteme$ nano b0
   ...
   Package: b
   Version: 1.0.0
   ...
   Depends: a
   ...
   ~/deleteme$ equivs-build b0
   ```

   A 1.0.0 clean install & remove

   ```
   ~/deleteme$ equivs-control a0
   ~/deleteme$ nano a0
   ...
   Package: a
   Version: 1.0.0
   ...
   ~/deleteme$ equivs-build a0
   ```

   A 1.0.1 dirty install, but clean remove

   ```
   ~/deleteme$ cp a0 a1
   ~/deleteme$ nano a1
   ...
   Package: a
   Version: 1.0.1
   ...
   Postinst: a1.postinst
   ...

   ~/deleteme$ nano a1.postinst

   #!/bin/sh    
   exit 1

   ~/deleteme$ equivs-build a1
   ```

   Now, you should have:

   ```
   ~/deleteme$ ls -1
   a0
   a1
   a_1.0.0_all.deb
   a_1.0.1_all.deb
   a1.postinst
   b0
   b_1.0.0_all.deb
   ```
2. Try this scenario

   ```
   sudo su

   dpkg -i b_1.0.0_all.deb
   dpkg --audit
   dpkg -i a_1.0.0_all.deb
   dpkg --audit
   dpkg --configure -a
   dpkg --audit
   dpkg --remove a
   dpkg --remove b
   dpkg --remove a

   dpkg -i a_1.0.0_all.deb
   dpkg -i b_1.0.0_all.deb
   dpkg --audit
   dpkg -i a_1.0.1_all.deb
   dpkg --audit
   dpkg --remove a
   apt purge a
   ```
3. To get in a loop where you can't complete installation neither remove it.

   Create clean A 1.0.1, B 1.0.0 but A 1.0.0 with a `Prerm:` script that contains `exit 1`. So when you try to install A 1.0.1, dpkg will fail to remove A 1.0.0 .

Answer (score 0):

If the dependencies `A` have changed on the installed package `B` you will see an error after performing `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` the package will be marked as `kept back`:

```
The following packages have been kept back
B-1.0.0
```

`dpkg` will not help you , if an upgrade is available `B-1.0.1`only `apt-get dist-upgrade`  will be helpful.